# Gradle run configurations with different properties

Tags: java, gradle

Here is my inputs:

Main.java

```
package com;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("greeting.language"));
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

mainClassName = "com.Main"

applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Dgreeting.language=en"]
```

My question: How can I configure another run task configuration to use different jvm arguments, for example: -Dgreeting.language=ch.

I moved to gradle from maven, so for such case I would use maven profiles. Is there any strucrure in gradle which corresponds to profiles?

**UPDATE 1**

Let me clarify a task a little bit. My project is far more complex that example I gave above. I would like to have a set of gradle tasks(or profiles/or whatever it's called in gradle), each of the task should be self-contained with custom set of variables. As an output I would like to have set of gradle task:

```
gradle <enableAllFeatures>
gradle <disableFeatureA>
...
```

It is not a requirement for these variables to be JvmArgs. It could be constants(or whatever possible in gradle) but it is **requirement to have different tasks**, and **each task should specify it's own set of variables**

**UPDATE 2**

I was surfing internet and found out very interesting topic - **gradle build variants**, but it is seems to be applicable only to android projects. Is it possible to use build variants in java projects?

Comment: Build variants You mentioned are android only. You can just simulate them in multiple ways.

Comment: Could you please describe them or share link where these ways are described?

Comment: I just know about them :/ You can e.g. use filtering with `ReplaceTokens` filter, apply from different settings, task rules. Gradle is really flexible tool..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameterize the language like this:

```
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Dgreeting.language=${language}"]
```

Then when you run Gradle, pass the language as a parameter using the -P option:

```
$ gradle -Planguage=en tasks
```

or

```
$ gradle -Planguage=ch tasks
```

**References**

[Gradle Goodness: Using Properties for Multiple Environments or Profiles](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/gradle-goodness-using-properties-for.html)

[Similar Maven profile Gradle](http://www.coderanch.com/t/603665/tools/similar-Maven-profile-Gradle)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not exactly what i would like to do. I want to avoid specifiyng parameters in command line. My project i far more complex, and uses far more variables. My goal is: when new team member comes into project - he runs just `gradle <some_task>` and have all project up and running avoiding any configuration.

Comment: Ok, that wasn't clear from your question. What you're looking for is on the page I referenced [Similar Maven profile Gradle](http://www.coderanch.com/t/603665/tools/similar-Maven-profile-Gradle). Please read that and let me know whether it can work for you.

Comment: I am also looking for an answer to that question. I want to have a long list of tasks and to be able to run them providing them with args, so that the main(args: String) can pick those args and work on them. I want to run my kotlin program like ./gradlew task1, ./gradlew2 task2... and each task to be able to internally supply the 'run' with different args. Any solution to that?